# Volunteer Form should come back to usual state after form submission

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, forms

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const validateAge = age => /^\d{2}$/.test(age);
  const validatePhone = phone => /^[+]?[0-9]{0,3}[ ]?[0-9]{6,12}$/.test(phone);
  const setStep = step => {
    document.querySelectorAll(".step-content").forEach(element => element.style.display = "none");
    document.querySelector(`[data-step="${step}"]`).style.display = "block";
    document.querySelectorAll(".steps .step").forEach((element, index) => {
      index < step - 1 ? element.classList.add("complete") : element.classList.remove("complete");
      index == step - 1 ? element.classList.add("current") : element.classList.remove("current");
    });
  }

  let currentStep = 1;

  document.querySelectorAll("[data-set-step]").forEach(element => {
    element.onclick = event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      // Check if all required fields are filled before proceeding to next step
      const $currentStep = $(`[data-step="${currentStep}"]`);
      const $nextStep = jQuery(`[data-step="${currentStep + 1}"]`);
      const $step = $currentStep.find('.step-content');
      let valid = true;

      $currentStep.find('input[required]').each(function() {
        const $input = $(this);
        const $error = $input.next('.error-message');
        if (!$input.val()) {
          if (!$error.length) {
            const $newError = $('<span class="error-message">This field is required</span>');
            $input.after($newError);
          }
          $input.addClass('error');
          valid = false;
        } else if ($input.attr('type') === 'email' && !/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test($input.val())) {
          if (!$error.length) {
            const $newError = $('<span class="error-message">Please enter a valid email</span>');
            $input.after($newError);
          }
          $input.addClass('error');
          valid = false;
        } else if ($input.attr('name') === 'age' && !validateAge($input.val())) {
          if (!$error.length) {
            const $newError = $('<span class="error-message">Please enter a valid age format</span>');
            $input.after($newError);
          }
          $input.addClass('error');
          valid = false;
        } else if ($input.attr('name') === 'phone' && !validatePhone($input.val())) {
          if (!$error.length) {
            const $newError = $('<span class="error-message">Please enter a valid phone number</span>');
            $input.after($newError);
          }
          $input.addClass('error');
          valid = false;
        } else {
          $input.removeClass('error');
          $error.remove();
        }
        // Add event listener to remove error message when the user starts typing
        $input.on('input', function() {
          $input.removeClass('error');
          $error.remove();
        });
      });

      if (valid) {
        // Proceed to next step
        $currentStep.hide();
        $nextStep.show();
        currentStep = currentStep + 1;
        setStep(currentStep);
      } else {
        // If the form is not valid, do not prevent the default behavior
        event.returnValue = true;
        return true;
      }
    }
  });
  $('.btn.alt').click(function() {
    var prevStep = currentStep - 1;
    var $currentStep = $(`[data-step="${currentStep}"]`);
    var $prevStep = $(`[data-step="${prevStep}"]`);

    // Go back to previous step
    $currentStep.hide();
    $prevStep.show();
    currentStep = prevStep;
  });


  // Define the submitForm function
  function submitForm() {
    // Send AJAX request to the server
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'form.php',
      data: $('#volunteer-form').serializeArray(),
      xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
      },
      success: function(response) {
        handleSuccess();
      },
      error: function() {
        handleFailure();
      }
    });
  }
  // Add event listener for form submission
  $('#volunteer-form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent the default form submission behavior
    submitForm();
  });

  // Function to handle success after form submission
  function handleSuccess() {
    // Reset the form
    document.querySelector("#volunteer-form").reset();

    // Show the success message
    const successMessage = document.querySelector("#success-message");
    successMessage.style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(function() {
      successMessage.style.display = "none";
      $('#volunteer-form')[0].reset();
      $('.steps .step').removeClass("current complete");
      $('.steps [data-step="1"]').addClass("current").removeClass("complete");
      $('.step-content').hide();
      $('[data-step="1"]').show();
    }, 3000);

  }

  function handleFailure() {
    // Show the error message
    const errorMessage = document.querySelector("#error-message");
    errorMessage.style.display = "block";

    // Hide the error message after 3 seconds
    setTimeout(() => {
      errorMessage.style.display = "none";
    }, 3000);
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  background: #f8f9f9 linear-gradient(0deg, #f8f9f9 0%, #f8f9f9 80%, #51b47c 80%, #51b47c 100%) no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
}

input,
textarea,
select {
  outline: 0;
}

.survey-form {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 680px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.survey-form select option:first-child {
  display: none;
}

.survey-form .buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid #eceff2;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.survey-form .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #5f9f19;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 6rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.survey-form .btn.alt {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #c9704c;
  color: #c9704c;
}

.survey-form .btn.alt:hover {
  border: 1px solid #c26c4a;
  color: #c26c4a;
}

.steps {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 35px);
  align-self: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.steps::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #f2f4f7;
  margin: auto 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.progress-line {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #238c00;
  margin: auto 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.steps .step {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #f2f4f7;
  border: 3px solid #f2f4f7;
  border-radius: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.steps .step.current {
  background-color: #008ffb;
}

.steps .step.complete {
  background-color: #238c00;
}

.progressLine {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #008ffb;
  margin: auto 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.steps::before.progressLine {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.survey-form .step-content {
  display: none;
}

.survey-form .step-content.current {
  display: block;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.step-content {
  padding: 2rem;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .survey-form {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 1.5rem;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="number"],
textarea {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0.5rem auto;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  background: rgba(116, 152, 104, 0.32);
}

.step-content p {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 120px;
  align-items: center;
}

.survey-form span {
  display: block;
  color: #238c00;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: clamp(1.2rem, 10vw, 2.5rem);
}

.survey-form h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

span.error-message {
  color: red;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  display: none;
}

input.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input.error+.error-message {
  display: flex;
}

input[type="radio"]:focus~.error-message {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked~.error-message {
  display: none;
}

#success-message,
#error-message {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

#success-message {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#error-message {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.fields {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.fields .input-field {
  display: flex;
  width: calc(100% / 2 - 15px);
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 14px 0;
}

.input-field input,
select {
  outline: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #333;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 0 15px;
  height: 42px;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

.input-field select {
  color: #707070;
}

.input-field input :focus,
.input-field select:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
}

.input-field label {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #2e2e2e;
}

.input-field select option {
  display: block !important;
}

input[type="textarea"] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #dfe0e0;
  width: 100%;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 47px;
}

.survey-form .steps::before.active {
  background: #f58;
}

.fiedls .input-field1 {
  margin-top: 0.8rem;
}

.input-field1 {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0.9rem;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .fields .input-field {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.6rem;
  }
  .fields .input-field1 {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.6rem;
  }
  .step-content {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="volunteer-form" class="survey-form" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="
        <?php echo $token?>" />
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="images/hero/logo.png" alt="Being Academy">
  </div>
  <span>Being Academy</span>
  <h1>Learners Form </h1>
  <div class="steps">
    <div class="step current"></div>
    <div class="step"></div>
    <div class="step"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="step-content current" data-step="1">
    <div class="fields">
      <div class="input-field">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First Name" required>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" placeholder="Your email">
      </div>
      <div class="input-field">
        <label for="age">Age</label>
        <input type="number" id="age" name="age" placeholder="Your Age" required>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field">
        <label for="phone">Phone/Mobile Number</label>
        <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" pattern="[+]?[1-9]\d{1,14}" required>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field1">
        <label for="address">Address</label>
        <textarea id="address" name="address" placeholder="Type Your Address" required></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field">
        <label for="gender">Gender</label>
        <select name="gender" id="gender" required>
          <option disabled selected>Select gender</option>
          <option value="male">Male</option>
          <option value="female">Female</option>
          <option value="others">Others</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field">
        <label for="engagement">Current Engagement </label>
        <select name="engagement" id="engagement" required>
          <option disabled selected>Select profession</option>
          <option value="Profession">Profession</option>
          <option value="work">Work</option>
          <option value="studies">Studies</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-set-step="2">Next</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- page 2 -->
  <div class="step-content" data-step="2">
    <div class="fields">
      <div class="input-field1">
        <label for="questions">What are your current challenges, wonders or questions in life ?</label>
        <input type="text" id="questions" name="questions" placeholder="life's Journey" required>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field1">
        <label for="share">Share any one thing that you've been pursuing or exploring for a long time <br> (more than a year at least...) </label>
        <input type="text" id="share" name="share" placeholder="Exploration" required>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field1">
        <label for="world">How do you look at the world today ?</label>
        <input type="text" id="world" name="world" placeholder="world today" required>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field1">
        <label for="issues">What do you think are major issues today ?</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="issues" name="issues" placeholder="major issues" required>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field1">
        <label for="engage">Amongst the above, what is that one issue that you wish to engage with to at least try and seek solution or answers...</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="engage" name="engage" placeholder="solution" required>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <a href="#" class="btn alt" data-set-step="1">Prev</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-set-step="3">Next</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- page 3 -->
  <div class="step-content" data-step="3">
    <div class="fields">
      <div class="input-field1">
        <label for="interest">What interested you to join being academy?</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="interest" name="interest" placeholder="joining academy" required>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field">
        <label for="course">How did you get to know about this course?</label>
        <select name="course[]" multiple>
          <option value="friends">Friends</option>
          <option value="whatsapp">Whatsapp</option>
          <option value="youtube">Youtube</option>
          <option value="facebook">Facebook</option>
          <option value="instagram">Instagram</option>
          <option value="other">Other</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field">
        <label for="finance">Will you be able to contribute financially ?</label>
        <select id="finance" name="finance" required>
          <option value="finance-yes">Yes, I can pay for myself and may be support others if needed</option>
          <option value="finance-myself">Yes, I can pay for myself</option>
          <option value="finance-partial">No, I need partial sponsorship</option>
          <option value="finance-no">No, I need full sponsorship</option>
          <option value="finance-sure">Not sure yet:</option>
          <option value="finance-other">Other</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field1">
        <label for="feedback">Do you have any questions for us or any concerns or feedbacks ?</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="feedback" name="feedback" placeholder="Any Questions" required>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <a href="#" class="btn alt" data-set-step="2">Prev</a>
        <?php if (!empty($messages)) { ?>
        <div class="error">
          <?php echo $messages[0]; ?> </div>
        <?php } ?> <input type="submit" class="btn" name="submit" value="Submit">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="success-message">Thank you for your submission!</div>
    <div id="error-message">Something went wrong!!!!</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I was working on the following volunteer form.

Form Works with **two issues** as it submits successfully and resets the form fields.

1. After submission and coming back to data-step 1 the **`form is not active`**
2. The next button is prevented to **`go to the next page or step`**

If you observe div step current is removed after submission which should not be the case in my finding.

I don't know where I am going wrong or unable to fix the issue. Please help me to fix this issue.